# How to permanently remove private browsing in Mozilla Firefox 109. Running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: firefox

I've tried to add a policies.json file in usr/lib/firefox/distribution/
I believe that the problems comes since I don't have any firefox folder, so no distribution folder.
Then I create firefox and distribution folder, I add the policies.json file, reboot the system, and nothing happened.

The policies.json contain the following text:

```
    {
      "policies": {
        "DisablePrivateBrowsing": true
      }
    }
```

Comment: This issue may be due to the snap package, which is unable to see the configs you changed. Switch to the APT version and it should work. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

Comment: It works, really thank you! 
I let below the link of how to install apt and remove snap
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22

Answer (score 0):

The solution did not work because the snap package is sandboxed and it cannot find these configs. The workaround is to use the apt version instead. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22) answer explains how to do that.